# Using bash (parameter expansion) to sanitize input file

Tags: regex, bash, shell, grep

I have a bash script that has a function like so:

```
sanitize(){

rb_reg="^([0-9]{1,3})\.([0-9]{1,3})\.([0-9]{1,3})$"

if grep -Ex "${rb_reg}" "${1}/.ruby-version" > /dev/null 2>&1; then
  sanitize_tmp="$(<"${1}"/.ruby-version)" &&
    ruby_version="${sanitize_tmp//[^0-9\.]/}" &&
    echo "Setting Ruby Version: ${ruby_version}"
else
  echo "There was an error trying to sanitize a .ruby-version file"
  echo "The file was: ${1}/.ruby-version"
  exit 7
fi
}
```

I'm using it to check a .ruby-version file and then set the version in there as a variable.
Mostly these files will contain something sensible like: 2.0.0 which works OK. I want to be defensive and not trust the input file, so check/sanitize it as much as possible.

Two questions:

If for some reason there were multiple version numbers in the file on multiple lines, say:

'2.0.0

1.0.0'

That's going to smash them together currently removing white space and end up with a variable like:    '2.0.01.0.0'
What's a good way to only pick up the first version number that matches the regex?

Is there a better way to do this, maybe entirely in bash without grep? Appreciate any examples people have of checking for a version like this but not trusting the input file.

Comment: The first case can't happen, because your regex is both anchored at start and end of line, plus grep's `-x` option requires the whole line to match - unless there can be multiple lines, that is.

Comment: Ah good catch. made it a bit clearer with an edit. Yeah for the first case I'm talking about multiple lines in the file. So the regex matches on the first example, and then the file has other lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still playing around with this a little, but here is what I ended up doing.
I'm passing in the file name as an argument to the function elsewhere in the script. Really liked the concept of BASH_REMATCH, so tried to avoid using grep, sed, awk etc and do it this way.

You can view the latest version of the code here: https://github.com/octopusnz/scripts

```
sanitize(){

  if [[ "${#}" -ne 1 ]]; then
    echo "[ERROR 7]: We expected 1 argument to the sanitize() function."
    echo "But we got ${#} instead."
    exit 7
  fi

  rbv_reg="^([0-9]{1,2})\.([0-9]{1,2})\.([0-9]{1,2})(-([a-z]{1,10}))?$"
  reg_matches=0

  while read -r rbv_line || [[ -n "$rbv_line" ]]; do

    if [[ "${rbv_line}" =~ ${rbv_reg} ]]; then
      ruby_version="${BASH_REMATCH[0]//[^0-9a-z\.\-]/}" &&
        ((reg_matches="${reg_matches}"+1)) &&
        echo "" &&
        echo "Setting Ruby version: ${ruby_version}" &&
        break
    fi
  done < "${1}"

  if [[ "${reg_matches}" -lt 1 ]]; then

    if [[ -v ruby_version ]]; then
      echo "We couldn't parse ${1} and set a valid Ruby version."
      echo "Using default: ${ruby_version}"
    else
      echo "We couldn't parse ${1} and set a default Ruby version."
      echo "[ERROR 4]: No valid .ruby-version file found."
      exit 4
    fi
  fi
}
```